# Get taxonomy of a specific category - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with querying posts.
I need to get sizes only of specific brands.
I have cpt 'installation_files' which has different taxonomies 'sizes' and 'brands'. My code does query all sizes of a specific brand. I need to list only those sizes that are available in this specific brand.

```
<?php

      $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'installation_files',
        'brands'    => $diagram->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'order'    => 'ASC'
      );
     $posts = get_posts($args);
     if( $posts ) :?>
                                        
     <form class="js-filter-form" data-brand="<?php echo $diagram->term_id; ?>">
          <select name="categories">
              <?php 
                                                
                 $cat_dropdown_args = array(
                 'option_all'  => __( 'Any Size' ),
                 'taxonomy' => 'sizes',
                                                   
                  'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                      'field'    => 'slug',
                      'terms'    => array( $diagram->slug) ,
                      ),
                   ),
                  );
                                                    
                                                                                                    
                 $categories = get_categories($cat_dropdown_args);         ?>
                                                    
                 <option class="js-filter-item" value="">All Sizes</option>
                      <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
                           <option class="js-filter-item" value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>">
                                  <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                           </option>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
               </select>
       </form>
```

At this moment I get ALL cpts and a select form to choose from different sizes. So the problem is that list of sizes contain some sizes not present in these brands.
Filtering and displaying posts work fine, it shows that there is no posts with such a size. However, to avoid it, it will be great to have only those sizes available with a specific brand.